# Identify this space combat game with a letter based ship architecture

Tags: identify-this-game

I remember going through an old board game I found in my parents attic when I was a child (early 2000s, however it's an old game, so it could easily have been released in the 80s) and I was hoping you could all help me.

It was a hex-based space combat game, where players designed their fleets to a set number of points (and a desired Tech Level) before play. This box set had little cardboard counters for the ships, although there was a leaflet inside for ordering little cast model ships in various styles.

The most unique part was how the ship was described. It consisted of a bunch of letters in a row, each one representing a single module. Damage would typically involve crossing out letters from left to right, although some weapons had different rules.

An example (off the top of my head):

> SSSSAAAHHPdGGOIIII

This would represent a ship with 4 units of shields, 3 armour, some holds, Point Defence and other gubbins, and finally four Ion Engines. So this ship would lose its Shields and Armour first and would lose the engines last.

Finally, I remember there was an expansion pack that brought a new faction along with rules for fighter craft.

Does anyone know what this game is called?

Comment: Could you provide context to "when I was a child"? (e.g., what year or decade are we talking about?)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Could this have been part of the [Starfire](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2891/starfire) series?  Images show a hexagonal grid & ship counters and the description says:

> A "word" makes up a ship. As damage is done between ships, letters are
> crossed off from left to right within the "word" until the ship is
> destroyed.

Comment: The review at https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1101304/starlord-review-quick-and-simple-game-yesteryear provides even more corroboration: "Damage Allocation: Damage is applied by deleting systems from left to right, bypassing systems that the weapon doesn't affect. So if the the ship SAIGIRII takes 4 standard damage, it looks like this S-A-I-G-IRII having lost a shield (S), armour (A), ion engine (I) and gun (G)."

Comment: This definitely looks like it. Is the culture here to accept an answer immediately, or should I wait for 24 hours like some other SEs suggest?

Comment: @Kyyshak: In the case of questions tagged as identify-this-game, I don't think there's much reason to hold out for additional, better answers.

Comment: https://www.nobleknight.com/P/2147353865/Starfire-I

Comment: Starfire II was the fighter expansion, and Starfire III: Empires was a campaign game with (if I remember correctly) randomly generated star systems and hyperspatial connections between them.